# How to limit grease pencil draw area to inside of closed curve?

Tags: grease-pencil, 2d

Suppose I draw a closed curve with the grease pencil.

The fill tool works on this curve, so it seems to have no trouble having its inside detected.

Can I somehow constrain my grease pencil (or better, a specific material of the grease pencil) to only draw inside this curve?

Comment: I think you would have to use a mask set to holdout with another layer which fills the outside of the curve

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be achieved by masking a layer by another one.
On 2.91 here's how i will do it :

1 : enable masking on the desired layer
[image: step 1]

2 : select the mask layer from a list
[image: step 2]

3: turn the mask layer invisible
[image: step 3]

Step 3 can be done by several ways, like turning down layer's opacity or as Gorgious said, setting the grey material as a holdout.

Note that there is a mask toggle icon next to the layer's names in properties and dopesheet areas.

Comment: Thank you, this is perfect!